# How do i limit in sql, that if one table row is selected, only corresponding items from another table show?

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys

For example, i have two tables with the names of "Clothing" and "Colors"

Now I want to limit, which colors can be chosen when selected a certain item.

Example: I have these two items in Clothing: Pants and Tshirt.
And 3 items in color: Red, Green and Black.

Now when I select Pants, i only want to be able to select the colors red and green. When I select Tshirt, then only black and green.

What I tried is:

- Make a table called 'clothing' with the columns ID, name
- Make a table called 'color' with the columns ID, name and clothingID (foreign key)
- Make a table called 'order' with the columns ID, clothingID (foreign key) and colorID (foreign key)

My table 'clothing':

ID: 1; name: pants

ID: 2; name: tshirt

After that i filled my table 'color' with these 4 items:

ID: 1; name: red; clothingID: 1

ID: 2; name: green; clothingID: 1

ID: 3; name: black; clothingID: 2

ID: 4; name: red; clothingID: 2

and now the 'order' table should not be able to e. g. select a red tshirt.
However, it doesn't work. I don't know how to advance as I even have got some redundancies in my 'color' table and also do not know where to search to resolve the issue...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say that these are your tables `clothing` and `order`:

```
create table clothing(id int primary key, name varchar(20));
insert into clothing(id, name) values
(1, 'pants'), (2, 'tshirt');                                         

create table color(id int primary key, name varchar(20));
insert into color(id, name) values
(1, 'red'), (2, 'green'), (3, 'black');
```

Now create another table `clothingcolor` where you store the combinations of clothing and color that you want to allow:

```
create table clothingcolor(
  clothingid int, 
  colorid int,
  PRIMARY KEY (clothingid, colorid),
  FOREIGN KEY (clothingid) REFERENCES clothing(id),
  FOREIGN KEY (colorid) REFERENCES color(id)
);
insert into clothingcolor(clothingid, colorid) values
(1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 1), (2, 3);
```

Finally your `order` table:

```
create table `order`(
  id int,
  clothingid int,
  colorid int,
  FOREIGN KEY (clothingid, colorid) REFERENCES clothingcolor(clothingid, colorid)
)
```

contains a composite foreign key that references the table `clothingcolor` so you can only store `clothingid` and `colorid` combinations that exist in the table `clothingcolor`.
See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dMxepJjepgpG3g9gWCqnBa/0).

This design is just for guidance. 
There are and there will be other issues to be solved if you decide to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

First of all u should do a join table (with clothingID and colorID as foreign key and primary key) for these 2 entities, then u just do a query to select the right thing.

ex:
order: red t-shirt

query:

`select * from clothing c1 join clothingColors cc on c1.id = cc.clothingID join on colors c2 on cc.colorID = c2.id where c1.name = "t-shirt" and c2.name = "red"`

This query should return null in your case.

Answer (score 0):

On the table called 'order' with the columns ID, clothingID, and colorID make the foreign key both clothingID and colorId together.  Right now you have them as separate foreign keys, separately both are valid but as a combination they won't be valid.  You'll need to make a unique index on the color table to have clothingID and colorID.